# Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined error on firebase.initializeApp(Config)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i am trying to connect and fetch data from my firebase firestore database but I am having error on       `firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);`
error is **Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined**  I tried may ways that were told on different websites ut nothing worked kindly help my code is

```
 <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js'></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.22.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.22.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.22.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js" ></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>  
// Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "{{ config('services.firebase.apiKey') }}",
  authDomain: "{{ config('services.firebase.authDomain') }}",
  projectId: "{{ config('services.firebase.projectId') }}",
  storageBucket: "{{ config('services.firebase.storageBucket') }}",
  messagingSenderId: "{{ config('services.firebase.messagingSenderId') }}",
  appId: "{{ config('services.firebase.appId') }}",
  measurementId: "{{ config('services.firebase.measurementId') }}"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);        //getting error on this line
```

many answers i saw to reso;ve this issue were about include scripts that are already included i tried to include them in head too but not working i am working on local server

Answer (score 0):

You use JS modules scripts, but you need to include compatibility libraries as mentioned here https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#window-compat

rename files

```
firebase.js -> firebase-compat.js
firebase-app.js -> firebase-app-compat.js
firebase-firestore.js -> firebase-firestore-compat.js
firebase-auth.js -> firebase-auth-compat.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase's JavaScript SDKs support two syntaxes:

- The namespaced API that we initially introduced, which has a limited set of top-level service objects with nested method calls inside them.
- The modular API that we introduces in SDK version 9, which relies on many more top-level functions. This API has the advantage that unused functionality can be removed during the build process by a so-called bundler tool, which means that you end up with much smaller apps.

The code in your question uses a mix of these two syntaxes, which unfortunately isn't possible. The good news is that you have two options to move forward:

1. Either use the new modular SDK from a CDN, as shown in the [alternate setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/alt-setup) section of the documentation.
2. Or use the compatibility libraries that are built-into the newer SDK, so that you can continue to use the namespaced syntax. That path is documented in [Using the compat library from the window](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#window-compat).